# Case Statement for multiple criteria

Tags: sql

I would like to ignore some of the results of my query as for all intents and purposes, some of the results are a duplicate, but based on the way the request was made, we need to use this hierarchy and although we are seeing different 'Company_Name' 's, we need to ignore one of the results.

Query:

```
SELECT  
    COUNT(DISTINCT A12.Company_name) AS Customer_Name_Count,
    Company_Name,
    SUM(Total_Sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM 
    some_table AS A12
GROUP BY 
    2
ORDER BY 
    3 ASC, 2 ASC
```

This code omits half a doze joins and where statements that are not germane to this question.

Results:

```
  Customer_Name_Count     Company_Name           Total_Sales
-------------------------------------------------------------
1  3                       Blockbuster               1,000
2  6                       Jimmy's Bar               1,500
3  6                       Jimmy's Restaurant        1,500
4  9                       Impala Hotel              2,000
5  12                      Sports Drink              2,500
```

In the above set, we can see that numbers 2 & 3 have the same count and the same total_sales number and similar company names.  Is there a way to create a case statement that takes these 3 factors into consideration and then drops one or the other for Jimmy's enterprises?  The other issue is that this has to be variable as there are other instances where this happens.  And I would only want this to happen if the count and sales number match each other with a similar name in the company name.

Desired result:

```
  Customer_Name_Count     Company_Name           Total_Sales
--------------------------------------------------------------
1  3                       Blockbuster               1,000
2  6                       Jimmy's Bar               1,500
3  9                       Impala Hotel              2,000
4  12                      Sports Drink              2,500
```

Comment: Why don't you start by at least adding the query you're already using to pull this data

Comment: show also the expected result

Comment: What's your dbms?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the joins you are using are multiplying the number of rows. Somewhere along the way, multiple names are associated with exactly the same entity (which is why the numbers are the same). You can fix this by aggregating by the right id:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A12.Company_name) AS Customer_Name_Count,
       MAX(Company_Name) as Company_Name,
       SUM(Total_Sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM some_table AS A12
GROUP BY Company_id -- I'm guessing the column is something like this
ORDER BY 3 ASC, 2 ASC;
```

This might actually overstate the sales (I don't know). Better would be fixing the `join` so it only returned one name. One possibility is that it is a type-2 dimension, meaning that there is a time component for values that change over time. You may need to restrict the join to a single time period.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like other answers are accurate based on assumption that Company_IDs are the same for both.

If Company_IDs are different for both Jimmy's Bar and Jimmy's Restaurant then you can use something like this.  I suggest you get functional users involved and do some data clean-up else you'll be maintaining this every time this issue arise:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE
        WHEN A12.Company_Name = 'Name2' THEN 'Name1'
        ELSE A12.Company_Name
    END) AS Customer_Name_Count
   ,CASE
        WHEN A12.Company_Name = 'Name2' THEN 'Name1'
        ELSE A12.Company_Name
    END AS Company_Name
   ,SUM(A12.Total_Sales) AS Total_Sales
FROM some_table er
GROUP BY CASE
    WHEN A12.Company_Name = 'Name2' THEN 'Name1'
    ELSE A12.Company_Name
END
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to have function to return a common name for the companies and then use `DISTINCT`:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        Customer_Name_Count, 
        dbo.GetCommonName(Company_Name) as Company_Name, 
        Total_Sales
 FROM dbo.theTable
```

Comment: Thank you, but can you describe what the function would look like?  As I would only be able to use a common name if the sales and count matched, if they don’t match then I need to separate records(referring to this instance)

Comment: In your question you said "similar company names", so tell me first how do you find out two company names are similar?

Comment: In the example above, if two company name's started with 'Jimmy's...' I would like to do some kind of comparison that looked at count and sales figures and if these were a match, then collapse both records from 2 to 1.  If this is possible, the company name utilized could be either given name or a hard coded name, but we have several instances of this and I am trying to figure the best way to work around this.

Comment: It is going to be impossible to compare each two records to check if they are similar. You need to have a method to return a common name for similar names. I suggest to create a list of possible common names and map them to a single common name, like a table in the same database with two columns 'Actual Name', 'Common Name'

Comment: Ok thank you for your help, I didn’t think what I was asking was possible outright, but I have been working on SQL for less than a year.. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` with *window function* to make row number by `Customer_Name_Count` and `Total_Sales` then get `rn = 1`

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Customer_Name_Count,Total_Sales ORDER BY Company_Name) rn
    FROM (
        SELECT  
            COUNT(DISTINCT A12.Company_name) AS Customer_Name_Count,
            Company_Name,
            SUM(Total_Sales) AS Total_Sales
        FROM 
            some_table AS A12
        GROUP BY 
            Company_Name
    )t1
)t1
WHERE rn = 1
```